# Поочерёдное выполнение функций с таймерами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 функции : 
1)

```
function main() {
            setInterval(function (){
***любое действие***
,2000);
};
main();
```

2)

```
function main1(){
    $('body').show(2000);
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы 2-ая функция выполнялась не одновременно с 1-ой, а только после её окончания???

Пример по ссылке: `https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/LjLYZO`

Comment: Она так и выполняется.

Comment: У меня почему-то не выполняется поочередно. По ссылке оба элемента появляются одновременно, а не поочередно - https://codepen.io/alexseveneight/pen/LjLYZO. Что делать?